# Temporary public URL for Azure Blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I currently work with a VOIP product that allows our customers to record their phone calls. Recorded phone calls by default are stored on our servers, and a URL is stored which points to the recording, which is embedded in our customers' portals.

We are working on a feature that allows our customers to provide their own Azure Blob details, such that recordings are stored in their own container. The only problem we are having is that the container needs to be set to public so that the recording can be embedded dynamically in the browser.

The paths to the recordings contain multiple UUIDs, providing some kind of security through obscurity, although we still aren't too keen on requiring the containers to be public.

Does there exist a method in Azure Blob to generate temporary URLs/tokens for accessing files, such that we can refresh links (daily, for example) so that a bad actor couldn't share a recording with a link that will never cease to be valid?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview).

> A shared access signature (SAS) provides secure delegated access to
> resources in your storage account. With a SAS, you have granular
> control over how a client can access your data. For example:
>
> What resources the client may access.
>
> What permissions they have to those resources.
>
> How long the SAS is valid.